# Creating a variable name using a String value

Tags: java, class, variables, object

This is a simple question (I think)

Lets say I have this code (Assuming I have a dog class)

```
String name = "dog";
dog name = new dog();
```

How can I get java to recognize name as a String and name the object dog?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Surely there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: You probably should learn about Java's reflection API if that is what you want.

Comment: I think the title and the content of this question are inconsistent. It seems like you are *not* trying to create a variable whose name is based on the value of a string.  Rather it seems like you want to set the class of a variable based on the string value. If the latter is the case, the `Factory` pattern might help.

Comment: @fge: I think we need to know more about why he wants to do this. My experience here is that > 90% of the time reflection is not the solution to the over-all problem that the poster is trying to solve.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

While you can do what you're trying in some scripting languages such as PHP (and this question is often asked by many PHP programmers who start Java), this is not how Java works, and in fact variable names are a much less important than you may realize and hardly even exist after code is compiled. What is much more important and what is key are variable *references* -- the ability to gain access to a particular object at a particular point in your program, and you can have Strings refer to objects easily by using a Map as one way.

For example

```
Map<String, Dog> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Dog>();
dogMap.put("Fido", new Dog("Fido"));

Dog myPet = dogMap.get("Fido");
```

Or you can gain references to objects in many other ways such as via arrays, ArrayLists, LinkedLists, or several other collectinos.

**Edit**
You state:

> The thing is that in my code I am going to be using one method to create objects, the name of the object is arbitrary but I need it to be dynamic because it wont be temporary, so the actually name of the object has to change or I will be writing over the previously declared object.

This is exactly what I meant when I said that the name of the variable is not as important as you think it is. The variable name is ***not*** the "object name" (this really doesn't exist in fact).

For example if you create a dog in a variable named Fido, and then assign it to a new variable named spot, both variables, despite having different names will refer to the very same object:

```
Dog fido = new Dog;
Dog spot = fido; // now fido and spot refer to the same object
```

If you want to give a variable a "name" consider giving the class a name property:

```
class Dog {
   private String name;

   public Dog(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Now you can give each Dog object its own (semi) unique name if you wish.

Comment: The thing is that in my code I am going to be using one method to create objects, the name of the object is arbitrary but I need it to be dynamic because it wont be temporary, so the actually name of the object has to change or I will be writing over the previously declared object.

Comment: Well, the described method in this answer allows you to do just that!

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, I will post back in about thirty or so to tell you how it goes.

Comment: If I can't get a hash map to work for me I will post the full info of what I am trying to do (It is kinda long)

Comment: @charleshorvath: please let us know how it goes -- and good luck!!

Comment: It all worked out good! I figured out how to use the HashMap to map references of the object. Thanks a lot

Comment: I know this is really old @HovercraftFullOfEels, but I hope you see this. What if there are 2 different key-value in the HashMap with 2 different instances? Say `map.put("Cat", new Cat())`, how do you declare the HashMap? `HashMap<String, Object>`? How do you instantiate the class?

Answer (score 6):

I don't suppose you are thinking of [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)?

```
private static void test () {
  Animal animal = Animal.valueOf("Dog");
}

enum Animal {
  Dog,
  Cat,
  Cow,
  Pig,
  Rat,
  Ant,
  Gnu;
}
```