# How to use the contents of a String as the name of an object

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a variable name using a String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value)

Let's say that I want to do a for loop that creates 10 integers named num1, num2, num3....etc.

How can I do this? I cannot seem to find a way to use a predefined string as the name of an object.

Comment: why not create an array of strings?

Comment: Why? Variable names aren't something that should generally be determined at *runtime*. And is this part of some kind of course or something? We seem to have been getting variations on this question lately...

Comment: Probably the closest solution that's possible without going to unreasonable lengths is to use a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: The only way to do this is via bytecode manipulation, and it's generally not something you probably need or want to do.

Comment: This is asked here at least once a week if not more frequently, and the answer is always the same. For instance:  [Creating a variable name using a String value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value). Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do what you are asking. Based on what I think you are trying to accomplish, I think you should use an array or a list:

```
int [] num = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   num[i] = // something
}


List<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   num.add(/* something */);
}
```

Comment: Regardless of *why* he wants to do what he's asking, this has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Oh, it probably has *something* to do with it. But yes, it's not an answer to the question actually asked.

Comment: Fair enough, I've reworded to address the question that was actually asked.

Comment: There are ways to do what he's asking.  They are just extremely complex and completely impractical.

Comment: I guess this probably is the best way to do it. Before, I wanted to be able to have names to reference later, but it's not really that much of an inconvenience to just reference a spot in an array/list.  Thanks.