# Naming an object with a variable string

Tags: java, class, variables, object

My question is similar to:

[Creating a variable name using a String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value#new-answer).

But I was hoping to take a different angle on it.

The reason for wanting to name each object is so I can call on the specifically later, and create multiple objects using the same statement. Ideally, this is what I want to work.

```
String dogName = reader.nextLine();

int legs  = reader.nextInt();

char beenFed = reader.nextChar();

new dogName = dog(dogName, legs, fed) `
```

I know java can't accept the variable as the object name. But suppose I want to create three dogs, "Red", "Blue" and "Jeff", how could I configure it, so that later the user can enter

```
Red.getLegCount();

Blue.hasBeenFed();
```

etc.

How else can I create this scenario? If I'm wanting to make many differently named Dog objects, how do I do it? And if it isn't a good idea, what could I do instead?

PS - First post on Stack Overflow. Please guide with etiquette/formatting.

Comment: I see you edited this for me Stuart. Please tell me what I needed to do, so I can post correctly in the future.

Comment: Stuart just edit your post so your post became more readable especially in code part...

Comment: please close the question if your doubt has been answered :)

Comment: I understand my post was edited to become more readable. I would like to know how I could do it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a `HashMap`? What you basically need is a set of key-value pairs. This is exactly what HashMap does. A good link to start off:
http://tutorialswithexamples.com/java-map-and-hashmap-tutorial-with-examples/

Make your `Dog` class with dogName, legs, beenFed, other attributes..
Next, define a `HashMap<String,Dog>` with key being as `dogName` and Dog being the entire `Dog` object with all attributes. e.g

```
Dog red = new Dog("red",5,true);
hashmap.put(red.dogName, red);
```

Later if you want to access the Dog object, do `olddog = hashmap.get("red").` 
Now, you can do anything - `olddog.getLegs()` ...

Comment: +1. A Hashmap or simply a collection of dog objects would suffice. If you have some natural key for your object (like dog name, or combination of properties of a dog), then you can simply grab it from the collection.

Comment: IT doesn't seem like objects are being created using HashMap - although maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I still need to be able to query a dog object using getLegCount() from the dog class.

Comment: I've had a look at HashMap, and that's a good solution, however using a key works too, then using a getKey() function in conjunction with a compare to bring up a specific object. Thanks for your help!