# Using Variable Value as Another Primitive Variable's Identifier

Tags: java, identifier

There are a number of questions on StackOverflow in the same vein as this; however, those questions deal predominantly (if not exclusively) with: other languages (PHP, Javascript, Ruby), `Object` (reference) type variables (Java, C++), or utilizing a variable's value to determine another's type (Java) - all of which I know how to do.

#### Here's What I Am After:

I have a variable:

`String id = "variableIdentifier"`

Is it possible, then, to initialize an `int` (it may be possible with `Integer`) with the identifier set to the value of `String id`?

The result I am looking for is `int variableIdentifier` where the identifier - again - is coming from the value of `String id`.

#### Some (Bad) Pseudo Code:

```
String id = "variableIdentifier";
Integer [needs name from id] = 0;
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Could you share code? Possible solution is in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Actually there is a topic with the same question , take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, you cannot name variables dynamically. Closest thing to that would be using [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). (Or some other Map implementation)

```
hashMap.put(variableIdentifier,variableValue);  //put value
hashMap.get(variableIdentifier); //get value
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to hold off on accepting your answer for a few minutes. You are confirming what I think, too. Just want to be absolutely 100% before saying "yes". Edit: just tried to accept -- SO requires a wait.