# How to make method parameter String value as a reference name of Map object

Tags: java

I have method `getMap(String name, Integer value)` so inside method i'm creating new `HashMap()` object, but i want `HashMap()` object reference name as `String name` value

Here is my code, i know i should not do like this because `name` is String type, but just to show

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getMap("refMap", 10);

    }

public static void getMap(String name, Integer value) {

    Map name = new HashMap<>();  // Compile Error duplicate local variable
    //Map refMap = new HashMap<>(); i want like this

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] that we really can understand. So far I can see that you have a `String name`, a `Integer value` and you want to meddle with `Map` out of nowhere (you aren't even returning a `Map`!).

Comment: can you tell us why you need to create a variable name from the method parameter

Comment: it's just to learn Java has that feature or not, in some of the script languages we can achieve that

Comment: Does the `Map` *have* to be named `name`? In the comment you use `refMap` instead. Is this not an option? And what do you mean by ' want HashMap() object reference name as String name value'? Do you want to put the value `value` for the key `name` into the map? Also, what do you do with the new map? `getMap` sounds like you want to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know about HashMaps because of the code you have listed. You can use HashMaps to associate String values to specific objects which serves a similar purpose as naming the object as the String value parameter.

Check out this answer: [Creating a variable name using a String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value)

Comment: so just in one word this is not possible in this way, am i right?

Comment: Yes, this is not possible in Java. Although other languages like PHP offer support for this, Java was not designed to do this.